# How to add a configuration parameter with spaces on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline which builds a C++ project for that I am using MSBuild, untill now we were using the "Final" configuration parameter, but now I need to switch it to "Release Steam D3D11", when I try to do that I get an error on Jenkins when building the project I guess it is because of the spaces, how can I make Jenkins to take this parameter? this is what I have tried:

```
stage('Build'){
            steps{
                script {
                    def msbuild = tool name: 'MSBuild', type: 'hudson.plugins.msbuild.MsBuildInstallation'
                    bat "\"${msbuild}\" AoC/Source/project-GRDK.sln /t:Rebuild /p:configuration=Release Steam D3D11" 
                } 
            }
        }
```

I have also tried adding ' ' to the configuration name such as :

```
bat "\"${msbuild}\" AoC/Source/project-GRDK.sln /t:Rebuild /p:configuration='Release Steam D3D11'"
```

but it does not work neither as I get this error:
`00:00:01.407  MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.`

Answer (score 1):

I sorted it out in case somebody have the same issue, wrapping the string with spaces within `\" \"` does the job

```
bat "\"${msbuild}\" AoC/Source/age2-GRDK.sln /t:Rebuild /p:configuration=\"Release Steam D3D11\""
```